# How to stop click event of parent element when child controls are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I have the following html. My click event is being attached to a parent span of id "Treedrop", but whenever I am expanding or collapsing or selecting a node,it is calling the 'treedrop' click event after expanding or collapsing the tree.I tried doing event.stopPropagation(). But it did not work. Even when I am clicking on search text box,it is calling the 'treedrop' click event function.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="1row">
<div id="treedrop" class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container select2-container--above" dir="ltr" style="width: 816px;">
    <div class="selection">
        <div class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-8qp2-container" aria-owns="select2-8qp2-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-8qp2-result-8fea-AK">
            <div class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-8qp2-container"><span id="dropdownText" class="select2-selection__placeholder">Double Click Here</span></div><div class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
                <b role="presentation"></b>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
    <div class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--below" dir="ltr" style="width: 816px;">
        <div class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown">
            <input id="treeSearch" class="select2-search__field" type="search" tabindex="0" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" role="textbox">
        </div>
        <div class="select2-results" id="html1">               
            <ul class="firstLevel">
                <li>
                    Root node 1
                    <ul>
                        <li>Child node 1</li>
                        <li>Child node 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Root node 2</li>
                <li>Test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery and JavaScript code:**

```
$("#treedrop").on("click", function (evt) {           
    $(this).toggleClass("select2-container--open"); 
    evt.stopPropagation();
});

$("#html1").on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {          
    var i, j, r = [];

    var node = data.instance.get_node(data.selected);
    var parents = [];
    var xpathString = "/" + node.text;
    //node.parents = node.parents.pop();
    for (var i = 0; i < node.parents.length - 1; i++) {
        var parentdata = data.instance.get_node(node.parents[i]).text;
        xpathString = "/" + parentdata + xpathString;
        parents.push(parentdata);
    }

    $('#dropdownText').text(xpathString).removeClass("select2-selection__placeholder");          
}).jstree({
        "search": {
            "case_insensitive": true,
            "show_only_matches": true
        },
        "multiple": false,
        "plugins": ["search"]

    });
```

Comment: Advice: Don't use spans for everything. That's probably whats causing the problem.

Comment: `span` is not even allowed to contain `ul`, that’s invalid HTML - so go fix that first.

Comment: Too many span elements .. :|

Comment: but why it is calling the click event of parent span that is the main problem

Comment: the stopPopagation code should work fine. You know that the click event bubbles upwards right? so if you stop propagation at #treedrop the click event will not bubble up to the parent element ( in your case .1row). But it will already have been trigger on your child elements (i.e #treeSearch)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, determine what is handling your event.

If your child actually catches your event you can use

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

to prevent your event from propagating to a parent.

If a parent is catching your event you can use

```
z-index
```

to push child on top of (not above but over) the parent so that your click is taken by the child.

You can also use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

to prevent parent element from taking events but if it's over your child that won't solve your problem until you bring the child in front it will simply be the unclickable parent.

NOTE: It's been mentioned in comments so just a reminder, fix your HTML. 
Span is used for:

> The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.
>
> The  tag provides no visual change by itself.
>
> The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a
>   part of a document.

You are doing none of that except maybe the styling which you can also do with simple class

Answer (score 0):

I got to a solution after applying a check on event.target object.
I modified my "treedrop" element's click handler which is the root element in the context.

```
$("#treedrop").on("click", function (evt) {       
    if (evt.target.className.includes("select2") && !evt.target.className.includes("treeSearch")) {
        $(this).toggleClass("select2-container--open");
    }       
});
```